# Не выводит сообщение в консоль

Tags: c#

Не читает `Console.WriteLine(x);`

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a, x, y,b;
            Console.Write("a=");
            a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("b=");
            b= double.Parse( Console.ReadLine());

            for (x = a; x < b; x++);
            {
                if (x <= 3)
                {
                  y = Math.Log10(Math.Pow(x, 3));
                    Console.WriteLine("y=%if \t");
                    Console.WriteLine("x");
                }

                else if (3 < x && x < 4.5)
                {
                    y = 1 / Math.Abs(Math.Sin(x));
                    Console.WriteLine("y");
                    Console.WriteLine("x");
                }
                else if (x <= 4);
                {
                    y = 1 / Math.Cos(1 / x);
                    Console.WriteLine("y");
                    Console.WriteLine("x");
                }
            }                      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(x); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вы хотите, чтобы вместо `Console.WriteLine("x")` и аналогичные строк кода в консоль выводились значения переменных.

Всё что заключено в двойные кавычки* воспринимается как текст. Уберите кавычки и просто напишите `Console.WriteLine(x)`, аналогично для других переменных.

**всё что заключено в двойные кавычки воспринимается как текст, за исключением случаев, когда речь идёт об [интерполированных строках](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation).*